# Read web page contents for blind people in Android

Tags: android, web-content

I'm going to build an Android application for blind people. I need to implement the access of web pages for blind people. For example the blind user may be want to attempt online quizzes. So how can I make the speech enabled web page contents in android?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [Android TextToSpeech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html)